# How to get a value from Error message?

Tags: error-tracking, error-trapping

I've looked pretty hard for a solution to this issue with no luck.
Hope you could give me a clue:

When I run `NDSolve` I get the following error msg:

```
NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 8.26993343406667`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

The singularity is expected at this value and I wonder if I can automatically make the code run from 0 to the value from the error message.
(the value changes every time so i can't just change the solution region.)

Thanks,
Ofek.

Comment: If the solutions in the linked thread do not solve your problem, please edit your question to explain why they don't work, so we can release the hold.

Comment: The linked thread is exactly what i was looking for. Somehow I've missed that one. Thanks alot!